# How get custom user fields in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

How get the custom user fields in a plugin? I can get the normal fields like firstName like this `craft()->userSession->user->firstName` but how i can get a custom field i tried `craft()->userSession->user->customfieldname` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`UserSessionService::getUser` method](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/UserSessionService#getUser-detail) returns [a `UserModel`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/UserModel).

You can retrieve the custom fields from a `UserModel` as follows:

```
$userModel->getContent()->getAttribute('fieldName');
```

Or, following on from your example:

```
craft()->userSession->getUser()->getContent()->getAttribute('fieldName');
```

Comment: I tried this and it works but now I have a relation field and that's returns 'null'